# Spring Boot custom annotation design not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-annotations

I am following a tutorial by PacktPublishing where some annotations are used in an example,
but the code is from 2018 and there have probably been some changes.

Spring does not recognize the Annotation when creating a bean.

Specifically, here is an annotation design that just does not work for me locally:
[link](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Building-Applications-with-Spring-5-and-Vue.js-2/blob/master/Chapter12/vuejs.spring-boot.mysql/src/main/java/com/taskagile/web/socket/handlers/BoardChannelHandler.java)

Some important code snippets are:

```html
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Component
public @interface ChannelHandler {

  /**
   * Channel patter, alias of value()
   */
  String pattern() default "";

  /**
   * The channel pattern that the handler will be mapped to by {@link WebSocketRequestDispatcher}
   * using Spring's {@link org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher}
   */
  String value() default "";

}
```

```html
@ChannelHandler("/board/*")
public class BoardChannelHandler {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BoardChannelHandler.class);

  @Action("subscribe")
  public void subscribe(RealTimeSession session, @ChannelValue String channel) {
    log.debug("RealTimeSession[{}] Subscribe to channel `{}`", session.id(), channel);
    SubscriptionHub.subscribe(session, channel);
  }

  @Action("unsubscribe")
  public void unsubscribe(RealTimeSession session, @ChannelValue String channel) {
    log.debug("RealTimeSession[{}] Unsubscribe from channel `{}`", session.id(), channel);
    SubscriptionHub.unsubscribe(session, channel);
  }
}
```

```html
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface Action {

  /**
   * The action pattern. It needs to be an exact match.
   * <p>For example, "subscribe"
   */
  String value() default "";
}
```

**Can you see what the issue is here? Is there some other annotation missing for newer versions
of Spring?**

**UPDATE - adding other necessary code.**

```html
public class ChannelHandlerInvoker {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChannelHandlerInvoker.class);

  private static final AntPathMatcher antPathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();

  private String channelPattern;
  private Object handler;
  // Key is the action, value is the method to handle that action
  private final Map<String, Method> actionMethods = new HashMap<>();

  public ChannelHandlerInvoker(Object handler) {
    Assert.notNull(handler, "Parameter `handler` must not be null");

    Class<?> handlerClass = handler.getClass();
    ChannelHandler handlerAnnotation = handlerClass.getAnnotation(ChannelHandler.class);
    Assert.notNull(handlerAnnotation, "Parameter `handler` must have annotation @ChannelHandler");

    Method[] methods = handlerClass.getMethods();
    for (Method method : methods) {
      Action actionAnnotation = method.getAnnotation(Action.class);
      if (actionAnnotation == null) {
        continue;
      }

      String action = actionAnnotation.value();
      actionMethods.put(action, method);
      log.debug("Mapped action `{}` in channel handler `{}#{}`", action, handlerClass.getName(), method);
    }

    this.channelPattern = ChannelHandlers.getPattern(handlerAnnotation);
    this.handler = handler;
  }

  public boolean supports(String action) {
    return actionMethods.containsKey(action);
  }

  public void handle(IncomingMessage incomingMessage, RealTimeSession session) {
    Assert.isTrue(antPathMatcher.match(channelPattern, incomingMessage.getChannel()), "Channel of the handler must match");
    Method actionMethod = actionMethods.get(incomingMessage.getAction());
    Assert.notNull(actionMethod, "Action method for `" + incomingMessage.getAction() + "` must exist");

    // Find all required parameters
    Class<?>[] parameterTypes = actionMethod.getParameterTypes();
    // All the annotations for each parameter
    Annotation[][] allParameterAnnotations = actionMethod.getParameterAnnotations();
    // The arguments that will be passed to the action method
    Object[] args = new Object[parameterTypes.length];

    try {
      // Populate arguments
      for (int i = 0; i < parameterTypes.length; i++) {
        Class<?> parameterType = parameterTypes[i];
        Annotation[] parameterAnnotations = allParameterAnnotations[i];

        // No annotation applied on this parameter
        if (parameterAnnotations.length == 0) {
          if (parameterType.isInstance(session)) {
            args[i] = session;
          } else {
            args[i] = null;
          }
          continue;
        }

        // Only use the first annotation applied on the parameter
        Annotation parameterAnnotation = parameterAnnotations[0];
        if (parameterAnnotation instanceof Payload) {
          Object arg = JsonUtils.toObject(incomingMessage.getPayload(), parameterType);
          if (arg == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to instantiate parameter of type `" +
              parameterType.getName() + "`.");
          }
          args[i] = arg;
        } else if (parameterAnnotation instanceof ChannelValue) {
          args[i] = incomingMessage.getChannel();
        }
      }

      actionMethod.invoke(handler, args);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      String error = "Failed to invoker action method `" + incomingMessage.getAction() +
        "` at channel `" + incomingMessage.getChannel() + "` ";
      log.error(error, e);
      session.error(error);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
@Component
public class ChannelHandlerResolver {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ChannelHandlerResolver.class);

  private static final AntPathMatcher antPathMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();
  // The key is the channel ant-like path pattern, value is the corresponding invoker
  private final Map<String, ChannelHandlerInvoker> invokers = new HashMap<>();

  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  public ChannelHandlerResolver(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    this.bootstrap();
  }

  public ChannelHandlerInvoker findInvoker(IncomingMessage incomingMessage) {
    ChannelHandlerInvoker invoker = null;
    Set<String> pathPatterns = invokers.keySet();
    for (String pathPattern : pathPatterns) {
      if (antPathMatcher.match(pathPattern, incomingMessage.getChannel())) {
        invoker = invokers.get(pathPattern);
      }
    }
    if (invoker == null) {
      return null;
    }
    return invoker.supports(incomingMessage.getAction()) ? invoker : null;
  }

  private void bootstrap() {
    log.info("Bootstrapping channel handler resolver");

    Map<String, Object> handlers = applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(ChannelHandler.class);
    for (String handlerName : handlers.keySet()) {
      Object handler = handlers.get(handlerName);
      Class<?> handlerClass = handler.getClass();

      ChannelHandler handlerAnnotation = handlerClass.getAnnotation(ChannelHandler.class);
      String channelPattern = ChannelHandlers.getPattern(handlerAnnotation);
      if (invokers.containsKey(channelPattern)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Duplicated handlers found for chanel pattern `" + channelPattern + "`.");
      }
      invokers.put(channelPattern, new ChannelHandlerInvoker(handler));
      log.debug("Mapped channel `{}` to channel handler `{}`", channelPattern, handlerClass.getName());
    }
  }
}


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

**UPDATE 2**

I have managed to make ChannelHandler and Action annotations work by adding @Inherited annotation and using AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation() which traverses its super methods if the annotation is not directly present on the given method itself.

**However, I haven't managed to access custom annotation value of type parameter (ChannelValue)**

Here, `Annotation[][] allParameterAnnotations = actionMethod.getParameterAnnotations();`

returns null value.

**UPDATE 3 -> SOLVED**

Just add @Aspect annotation to your ChannelHandler implementation (e.g.
"BoardChannelHandler").

Comment: In what way are the annotation's not working? As far as Spring is concerned, anything annotated with `@ChannelHandler` is just a `@Component`. It'll get picked up by component scanning and turned into a bean, but that's it. `@Action` won't mean anything to Spring.

Comment: `ChannelHandler handlerAnnotation = handlerClass.getAnnotation(ChannelHandler.class);`

https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Building-Applications-with-Spring-5-and-Vue.js-2/blob/master/Chapter12/vuejs.spring-boot.mysql/src/main/java/com/taskagile/web/socket/ChannelHandlerResolver.java

returns NullpointerException

"Failed to instantiate ChannelHandlerResolver  Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: What do you mean by saying "@Action won't mean anything to Spring" ?

Comment: It's a custom annotation that Spring knows nothing about. Furthermore, there's no code in your question that will do anything with the `@Action` annotation. There might be in the GitHub repository that you've linked to, but you're more likely to get the answer you're looking for if the question itself contains all the necessary parts to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I've updated my question to include resolver and invoker classes that use the Action method which is received by the websocket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [bootstrap()](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Building-Applications-with-Spring-5-and-Vue.js-2/blob/master/Chapter12/vuejs.spring-boot.mysql/src/main/java/com/taskagile/web/socket/ChannelHandlerResolver.java#L26) method, that goes through all the `@ChannelHandler` annotated beans is executed too early - try to debug it to check if it detects any beans at this stage.

If not try calling `bootstrap()` after Spring context is ready (for example listen for `ContextRefreshedEvent`.

Comment: Exactly, you nailed it.
I tried, but it runs into the same error. But I am not sure if i did it right:
I've set ChannelHandlerResolver to implement ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>

And here's my overwritten method


`   @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        bootstrap();
    }`

Comment: I ended up debugging further, ContexRefreshedEvent is triggered, bootstrap() method is called, but AnnotationData and Annotation within handlerAnnotation is null and so the nullpointerException gets thrown all the same.

For some reason annotation is not recognized when 
applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(ChannelHandler.class) is called

Comment: Solved. @Aspect was missing on handler implementation. Will update the question.